# How do I get the speed up setting for the stock market in cookie clicker?

Tags: cheats, cookie-clicker

I had the speed-up option there at one point, but now it's gone and I want to experiment with the stock market and see what the patterns are.

What I mean by the speed-up option, is the buttons on the line graph of the stocks, there are, usually, 2 buttons that say Line Style and Color Mode, and at one point, on a cheated run, there was a button below those two buttons that said speed up and it reduces the tick speed to somewhere under a second and that's what I'm looking to learn how to activate.